# Не получается соединиться с сервером postgresql извне сети

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

Делаю курсовую, необходимо обеспечить доступ к базе данных извне сети. Адрес белый, статический. Порт на маршрутизаторе открыт. Сам сервер бд запущен на порту 5432. Пытаюсь подключиться к базе по внешнему адресу, вылезает ошибка, что сервер отклонил запрос. Подключаюсь через entity Framework из c#. При этом, при пробросе порта, например для ftp, все работает.

С чем может быть связана проблема?

Comment: Раз сервер виден и возвращает ответ, значит, проблема в настройках безопасности. Хорошо бы логи PosgreSQL'я почитать, что его не удовлетворило. Также перепроверьте правильность логина и пароля, заданных при подключении.

Comment: Думаю, может что-то с фаерволом, буду копаться

Comment: Фаерволл, я думаю, просто не пропустил бы пакет до СУБД и ответа Вы бы не получили, нужно покопаться в настройках PostgreSQL

Comment: Стоп. У меня возникает ошибка `Unhandled exception. Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.`. Подсказывает что даже пакет до бд не доходит, а бокируется где-то перед ней.

Comment: Все, заработало! Проблема была в том, что я пытался подключиться из локальной сети по внешнему адресу, а маршрутизатор блокировал такие запросы. Раздал мобильный интернет с телефона и все подключилось!